# Custom table view cell with Core graphics

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, calendar, core-graphics

I'm making a a table view where the user can select what Calendars the app should import inside, my purpose is make something similar to Cal: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i980yr70j0vq0p1/foto.PNG

So I create the TableViewController and inside the tableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath I create my custom cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
EKCalendar *calendar;
calendar = [theCalendarSyncEngine.calendars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
CalendarCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if(cell==nil){
    cell = [[CalendarCell alloc]initAndReuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier andIsChecked:FALSE andAColor:calendar.CGColor];
}
cell.title.text=calendar.title;
return cell;
}
```

The CalendarCell init method:

```
- (id)initAndReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier andIsChecked:(BOOL)checked andAColor:(CGColorRef)color
{
self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
       // Initialization code
       theColor=color;
       positionFrame = CGRectMake(30,self.contentView.bounds.size.height/2-2.5,5,5);
       circle=[[CircleView alloc]initWithFrame:positionFrame andAColor:theColor];
       title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, self.contentView.bounds.size.height/2-10, 230.0, 20.0)];
       title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
       title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
       title.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
       title.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
       checkbox = [[UISelectionCheckbox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270.0, self.contentView.bounds.size.height/2-10, 20, 20)];
       checkbox.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
       checkbox.checked = checked;
       [checkbox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxTouched:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       [self.contentView addSubview:circle];
       [self.contentView addSubview:circle];
       [self.contentView addSubview:title];
       [self.contentView addSubview:checkbox];
    }
    return self;
}
```

A Calendar cell has a CircleView that is a circle with the Calendar's color, a label with the Calendar's name and a Checkbox in order to select or not the Calendar.

Here's the CircleView code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andAColor:(CGColorRef)color
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
       [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
       thisColor = color;
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
   CGContextRef context= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGContextClearRect(context,rect);
   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, thisColor);
   CGContextSetAlpha(context, 1);
   CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(0,0,self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height));
   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, thisColor);
}
```

The problem is the CircleView, when I show the TableView every circle has the same color. Where I'm getting wrong?

#### UPDATE

I follow the hint and modified the code as below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
   EKCalendar *calendar;
   calendar = [theCalendarSyncEngine.calendars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   CalendarCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
   if(cell==nil){
       cell = [[CalendarCell alloc]initAndReuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier andIsChecked:FALSE];
   }
   cell.title.text=calendar.title;
   //UPDATE METHOD TO SET COLOR
   [cell setColor:calendar.CGColor];
   return cell;
}
```

The method inside CalendarCell:

```
- (void)setColor:(CGColorRef)color
{
    [circle setColor:color];
    [circle setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Which calls the CircleView method:

```
- (void)setColor:(CGColorRef)color
{
     thisColor=color;
}
```

Comment: Check value of theColor in CalendarCell init method. Is it same all the time? Then check thisColor in CircleView init method.

Comment: the code here: "if (cell==nil){...}" will never get called if you use storyboard/xib, so I guess your initAndReuseId method is never called.

Comment: I've already checked this and the color changes! So I think the problem refers to TableView methods.
@CalinChitu the method is called once a time for the number of cells, if I don't check this, every time a cell disappears it will be recreated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your setting the color of your cell inside the init method. Which means that if your cell is reused, the color will be the one during the creation of the cell.

You should move the set of the color **outside** the following block

```
if(cell==nil){
cell = [[CalendarCell alloc]initAndReuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier andIsChecked:FALSE andAColor:calendar.CGColor];}
```

Create a set color method in your custom cell. And call `cell.setColor()calendar.CGColor`

Moreover you may need to call setNeedDisplay on your circleView after to force call to redraw on reused cells.

Comment: I've made as you suggested, the situation has changed but on the first load the problem is still there, if I scroll the list the cell that disappears will change color.

Comment: The code looks ok for me now. You can maybe check that no variable are nil on first load. Sorry, didn't see what is still wrong